# default application is not shown on the emulator xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Actually I follow the instruction on deployment in Xamarin website but suddenly once i run the first sample application I can't find wheres the sample application can find in the emulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has it launched at all when you run your project?

Comment: What do you mean? The addded image above is what i have seen once i run in debug mode.

Comment: @Goi Did you get any errors on deploy? Sometimes it takes ages to deploy to built-in emulators? So you should be patient?